# Yii - CGridView - add own attribute

Tags: php, yii

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'title',          // display the 'title' attribute
        'category.name',  // display the 'name' attribute of the 'category' relation
        'content:html',   // display the 'content' attribute as purified HTML
        array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
            'name'=>'create_time',
            'value'=>'date("M j, Y", $data->create_time)',
        ),
        array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
            'name'=>'authorName',
            'value'=>'$data->author->username',
//HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
              'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'$data->author->username', 'secondAttribute' => $data->author->id),
//HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        ),
        array(            // display a column with "view", "update" and "delete" buttons
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

In option `value` i can add variable from PHP, but for option `htmlOptions` this is not possible. Why?
How can i make attribute with PHP variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add arrays in the [`columns`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail) collection without specifying a `class` property, the type of column being created is `CDataColumn`. The property `CDataColumn::value` is [explicitly documented](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) to be

> a PHP expression *that will be evaluated for every data cell* and whose
>   result will be rendered as the content of the data cells.

Therefore, `value` has the special property that it gets [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)'ed for each row and that's why you can set it "dynamically". This is an exception however, and almost nothing else  supports the same functionality.

However, you are in luck because the property [`cssClassExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#cssClassExpression-detail) is another special exception that covers exactly this usage case. So you can do it like this:

```
array(
    'name'=>'authorName',
    'value'=>'$data->author->username',
    'cssClassExpression' => '$data->author->username',
),
```

**Edit:** I made a mistake while copy/pasting from your example and did not notice that you were trying to do the same thing for additional attributes inside `htmlOptions` (I have now deleted the relevant part of the code).

If you need to add more options for dynamic values you have no choice but to subclass `CDataColumn` and override the `renderDataCell` method ([stock implementation is here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridColumn.php#125)).

Comment: this is same as in my example. this doesnt working - nobody show.

Comment: @DirkFograust: This is definitely **not the same** as your example. Take another look. Also, make sure you are using the latest version of Yii.

Comment: this working only for cssClassExpression, but for htmlOptions this is still NULL :(

Comment: @DirkFograust: I simply missed that, sorry. As I said, the two cases where it *does* work are exceptions, not the rule. If you need it for more attributes you must subclass `CDataColumn`.

Comment: OK, nothing happens :) but still still this doesnt working.  how can i make it? I have the same method renderDataCell as in stock impementation.

Comment: @DirkFograust: If you have the same method of course nothing will happen. See what it does with `cssClassExpression` and do something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this still applies or not (given that there is an accepted answer), but there is a slightly better solution in the form of "rowHtmlOptionsExpression". This specifies an expression that will be evaluated for every row. If the result of the eval() call is an array, it will be used as the htmlOptions for the <tr> tag. So you can basically now use something like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array
(
   ...
   'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => 'array("id" => $data->id)',
   ...
```

All your  tags will have an id attribute with the records' PK. 
Just modify the jQuery slightly to obtain the id from that tag instead of an extra column and you should be set.

Comment: great...just what I was looking for, but what a wierd syntax man!

Answer (score 2):

Extend the class CDataColumn

Under protected/components/ create the file DataColumn.php with the following content:

```
/**
 * DataColumn class file.
 * Extends {@link CDataColumn}
 */
class DataColumn extends CDataColumn
{
    /**
     * @var boolean whether the htmlOptions values should be evaluated. 
     */
    public $evaluateHtmlOptions = false;

    /**
    * Renders a data cell.
    * @param integer $row the row number (zero-based)
    * Overrides the method 'renderDataCell()' of the abstract class CGridColumn
    */
    public function renderDataCell($row)
    {
        $data=$this->grid->dataProvider->data[$row];
        if($this->evaluateHtmlOptions) {
            foreach($this->htmlOptions as $key=>$value) {
                $options[$key] = $this->evaluateExpression($value,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data));
            }
        }
        else $options=$this->htmlOptions;
        if($this->cssClassExpression!==null)
        {
            $class=$this->evaluateExpression($this->cssClassExpression,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data));
            if(isset($options['class']))
                $options['class'].=' '.$class;
            else
                $options['class']=$class;
        }
        echo CHtml::openTag('td',$options);
        $this->renderDataCellContent($row,$data);
        echo '</td>';
    }
}
```

We can use this new class like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'article-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'title',
        array(
            'name' => 'author',
            'value' => '$data->author->username'
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'DataColumn',
            'name' => 'sortOrder',
            'evaluateHtmlOptions' => true,
            'htmlOptions' => array('id' => '"ordering_{$data->id}"'),
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```