# Yii gridview rows onclick to expand and show detailview below the row in grid

Tags: gridview, yii

how to show a gridview like the grid in [GRIDVIEW WITH ROW EXPAND AND COLLAPSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWBO1.jpg)the grid should show normal datas in view when clicking the row that should show the details of a thecorresponding row ..please help inthis...
my output should be like

[image: MY GRID SHOULD BE LIKE THIS]

AND when i click the row it should expand and give details(the image will show table but thats need not i need to render the detail view in that.
[image]

**EDITED** i forgot to add onething the grid will load from one model and row details will load from another model.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'books-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->Projectwisereport(),
//'filter'=>$model,

'columns'=>array(

    array(
        'name'  => 'Project',
        'value' => 'Project::model()->findByPk($data->Project)->proj_name',
   'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Project::model()->findall(),'proj_id','proj_name'),
        ),

    'isbn_no',
    'source_type',
array(
        'name'  => 'complexity',
        'value' => 'Complexity::model()->findByPk($data->complexity)->Complexity_Name',
                                                      'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Complexity::model()->findall(),'id','Complexity_Name'),
       'footer'=>'Total Page',
        ),
      array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',
     'template'=>'{detail}',
     'buttons'=>array(
      'detail'=>array(
            'label'=>'Show Details', 
                    'url'  =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Process/View",   array("id"=>$data->book_id))',
                    'options'=>array('title'=>'Show details','class'=>'detailsLink'),
  'click'=>"$('#your-grid-book_id').on('click','.detailsLink',function(){
     var row=$(this).closest('tr');
      var url=$(this).attr('href');
   $.get(url,{},function(data){
  row.after(data.row);
     },'json');
     })",

            )
    ) 
)

),
    )); ?>
```

i trided this but no use grid is from books model and link to process model in the CButton column

Comment: @Jon as i am new to this concept i dont have any idea on combining gridview and detailview my mind is  totally blank in this task.so only posted concept and wating for any suggestion aor sample links.

Comment: @jon now edited my post visit that...

Comment: @ bool.dev i edited my post now see that and give suggestion in that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

In GridView:

```
'columns'=>array
     (
            'ID',
            array
            (
                  'name'=>'...',
                  'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'plus','id'=>$data->id),
                  'value'=>'...',
            ),
            ...
     ),
```

js code:

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
var data = $(this).attr('id');
var url = ...ajax url...
jQuery.ajax({
                'type':'post',
                'data':data,
                'url':url,
                'cache':false,
                'success':function(html){
                                                var new_data = $("<div></div>").attr("class", "appended_data").html(html).attr("id",data);
                                                $(this).parent().append(new_data);
                                                $(this).removeClass('plus');
                                                $(this).addClass('minus');
                                        }
        }); 
});
```

From your controller ajax action send data in trs(table rows)..I hope the code is self explainatory..

Comment: its not updating the grid pls elobarate your sample i use htmloptions in Cbuttoncolumn and in js gave var url  to the controller sction but no use i don know what i worng with my code

Comment: my code is `array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'template'=>'{detail}',
'buttons'=>array(
'detail'=>array(
'label'=>'Show Details', 
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'plus','id'=>'$data->book_id'))))
 `

Comment: my js in same view `<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('plus', "$('.plus').click(function(){
var data = $(this).attr('id');
var url = '/itrack/index.php?r=/Process/detail'
jQuery.ajax({
'type':'post',
'data':data,
'url':url,
'cache':false,
'success':function(html){
var new_data = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'appended_data').html(html).attr('id',data);
$(this).parent().append(new_data);
$(this).removeClass('plus');
$(this).addClass('minus');
}}); });");
?>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891340/yii-cgridview-add-own-attribute

Comment: this is the ready component http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/

Comment: There is an alternative way if you are prepared in adding the attribute to the tr-tag. I've added an extra answer in the question referred to in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

From Rajats answer I got it working like this:

In gridview button:

```html
array(
            'class' => 'ButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{view}{confirm}',
            'evaluateID' => true,
            'buttons' => array(
                'view' => array(
                    'icon' => 'info-sign white',
                    'url' => '#',
                    'options' => array(
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'view'),
                        'onclick' => 'javascript:toggleRow($(this).attr("id"))',
                        'class' => 'btn-primary',
                        'id' => '$data->id'
                    ),
```

To be able to assign ID to button from row data, you need to use a custom ButtonColumn class, I used the one posted here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/372/cbuttoncolumn-use-special-variable-data-for-the-id-in-the-options-of-a-button/

The javascript code:

```
function toggleRow(id) {
    if ($('#table'+id).length) {
        $('#table'+id).remove();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'post',
            'data': {
                "payment_id": id
            },
            'url': "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action'); ?>",
            'success': function (html) {
                var new_data = $("<tr></tr>").attr("class", "btn-danger").html(html).attr("id", "table"+id);
                new_data.insertAfter($('#' + id).parent().parent());
            },
            'error': function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in controller action find the model from the id provided by ajax and return a html string:

```
public function actionControlleraction(){
    if (isset($_POST['payment_id'])) {
        $payment = Payment::model()->findByPk($_POST['payment_id']);
        $html = $payment->createHtmlTable();
        print_r($html);
    }
}
```

In the above example, the html code for a table is generated in my payment model.